# Lagrange multiplier using eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier

I am following this [lecture notes](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_LAGRANGE_MULTIPLIERS.PDF) (page 10), Using eigenvectors to find the maximum and minimum values. I am having a difficult time understanding how matrix A was derived.

Find the maximum and minimum values of

$Q(X) = x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 -2xy +4xz+4yz$

subject to the constraint

$x^2 +y^2 +z^2 = 1 $

Matrix of Q is 
$$
A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 2 \\
    -1 & 1 & 2 \\
    2 & 2 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Multiply out $[x\; y\; z] A [x \; y \; z]^{T}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "twos in" notation for [quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form), we have by matrix multiplication that

$$
Q(X) = X^TAX = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x &y &z\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} & a_{10} & a_{20}\\
a_{01} & a_{11} & a_{21}\\
a_{02} & a_{12} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\end{pmatrix}\\
=a_{00}x^2+a_{11}y^2+a_{22}z^2+2a_{10}xy+2a_{20}xz+2a_{12}yz
$$

assuming that $A$ is symmetric (i.e. that $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$). So for you to construct your matrix, you take the coefficients of the three square terms, 1,1,2, and put them on the diagonal. And take the coefficients of the three cross-terms, -2,4, and 4, divide them by 2, and put them in the appropriate off diagonal spots, giving you the desired result.